# How to find length of ResultSet using IdocScript in Oracle UCM?

Tags: oracle-ucm, stellent, idocscript

I am trying to find number of rows in a ResultSet using idocscript. Is there an optimal way of doing other than looping through the ResultSet as below?

```
<$sampleRSLength=0$>
<$if rsExists("sampleResultSet")$>
  <$loop sampleResultSet$>
    <$sampleRSLength=sampleRSLength+1$>
  <$endloop$>
<$endif$>
```

Comment: As an FYI, I try to watch SO but you will get quicker assistance on a forum such as OTN: https://community.oracle.com/community/fusion_middleware/webcenter/webcenter_content/content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the answer myself after reading through the IdocScript [reference guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/doc.1111/e26694/idoc_script_reference.htm#WCCDV10673) in detail.

Idocscript has a method `rsNumRows()` which can be used for getting number of rows in a result set.

```
<$if rsExists("sampleResultSet")$>
 <$sampleRSLength=rsNumRows("sampleResultSet")$>
<$endif$>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<$sampleResultSet.#numRows$>
```

will also work.